# Javascript Minimum and Maximum Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the following to limit the value in the text field. It works great only that when user tries to delete and leave blank it does not let it. It will not remove the minimum.
Quantity:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="none" name="notepad_and_pen" id="notepad_and_pen" maxlength="10" style="width:50px" tabindex=4 onchange="this.value = (this.value > 999999) ? 999999 : ((this.value < 400) ? 400 : this.value);">
```

I also have this script in the header as a placeholder for blank text fields maybe this might effect in someway:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $(this).val('');
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'))
    }
}
);
```

Please need help. I am a total noob and anything you can teach would be great.Thanks to all.

Comment: What do you want it to do. What your experiencing is exactly what the script is doing.

Comment: Do an initial check and then bind an `onChange` eventListener. Should do the trick.

Comment: huh? i don't understand that. Please i am a noob to the 30th.

Comment: I want their to be a forced number(quantities) between a lower and max limit. But when the user decides to go back and delete the entry it will revert back to a blank text box with the placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `this.value` is a string. You're comparing it to a number. Convert it to a number before comparing, with something like:

```
parseFloat(this.value)
```

Of course, it makes it a lot easier to debug and work with if you don't use inline event handlers. You're already using jQuery, so try this:

```
$("#notepad_and_pen").on("change", function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        finalValue = $this.val(),
        myValue = parseFloat(finalValue);
    if (isNaN(myValue)) {
        finalValue = "";
    } else {
        if (myValue > 999999) {
            finalValue = 999999;
        } else if (myValue <= 0) {
            finalValue = "";
        } else if (myValue < 400) {
            finalValue = 400;
        }
    }
    $this.val(finalValue);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wTKxX/4/

Comment: This is getting closer to what Im looking for. only that I want any range number to be typed in between the lower 400 and the upper 999999. But if user goes back and deletes number it will go back to being blank with the place holder there.

Comment: @user2292469 I'm confused. That's exactly what it does. If you put something lower than 400, it makes it 400. If you put something higher than 999999, it makes it 999999. If you leave it blank or put an invalid number, it puts the `placeholder` in. Isn't that what you just said? Or are you saying that if you leave it blank, you want it to be 400, instead of the `placeholder`?

Comment: it works great! If you can, how do you add the functionality that if the user types in "0" it automatically goes blank and to the placeholder?

Comment: @user2292469 Just add an `else if (myValue === 0) { finalValue = ""; }` after the first `if`.

Comment: @user2292469 Sorry, I just went back and tested and found it wasn't working completely. I updated my answer with new code and a new jsFiddle. I think that should finalize some things. If it's 0 or less, it uses the placeholder. If it's less than 400, it uses 400. If it's greater than 9999999, it uses 9999999. And if it's not a number in the first place, it uses the placeholder.

Answer (score -1):

Limits on `#notepad_and_pen` can be imposed, and deletion allowed, with a one-liner.

[This page](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html) provides a way to detect whether or not placeholders are supported natively (thus avoiding the need for Modernizr).

And [this page](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html) provides a reasonable approach to handling placeholders non-natively.

Here's the combined code :

```
$(function() {
    //Impose limits on #notepad_and_pen
    $("#notepad_and_pen").on('change', function() {
        this.value = (this.value === '') ? '' : Math.max(400, Math.min(999999, Number(this.value)));
        //Use the following line to reject anything that's zero, blank or not a number, before applying the range limits.
        //this.value = (!Number(this.value)) ? '' : Math.max(400, Math.min(999999, Number(this.value)));
    });

    //With reference to http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html
    function supports_input_placeholder() {
      var i = document.createElement('input');
      return 'placeholder' in i;
    }

    //With reference to http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html
    // 1. Handle placeholders (in non-HTML5 compliant browsers).
    if(!supports_input_placeholder()) {
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.val('');
                input.removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function () {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                input.addClass('placeholder');
                input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();

        //2. Prevent placeholder values being submitted to form's action script
        $('[placeholder]').eq(0).closest('form').submit(function () {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function () {
                var input = $(this);
                if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
                    input.val('');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: tried this. It does the samething with the orginal inline one. When I type a number that it detects between the lower and upper range its ok and if its below the lower limit it forces the lower limit.However when I try to go back and delete the entry it forces to the lower limit instead of deleting and leaving blank with place holder.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I got hung up on simplifying the range check and forgot to address the question. Answer edited.

Comment: iThis also works  great! If you can, how do you add the functionality that if the user types in "0" it automatically goes blank and to the placeholder?

Comment: I've edited in an alternative line that will reject anything that's zero, blank or not a number. That should cater for most if not all eventualities.

Comment: Hey, I've always been suspicious that I rock - now I know for sure. Any chance you could upvote when SO allows, to kill that nasty -1 someone gave me (maybe with justification at that time).